# Calculate elasped Unix Time in loop

Tags: c#, vb.net, time, webrequest, elapsed

I'm doing these webrequests loops and I need to keep track of time (unix time) elapsed since first request. For ex:

```
    Dim post1 String = "http://www.xxx.com/......" & UnixTimeNow1stCall & "......"
    Dim postReq1 As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(post1), HttpWebRequest)

    Dim post2 String = "http://www.xxx.com/......" & UnixTimeElasped1stCall& "......"
    Dim postReq2 As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(post2), HttpWebRequest)


    Dim post3 String = "http://www.xxx.com/......" & UnixTimeElasped1stCall& "......"
    Dim postReq3 As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(post3), HttpWebRequest)

*LOOP again*
```

And so on. In other words, I need to lock the current Unix Time in the first call and whenever I call later (in spaces of 10 seconds), I need it to reference this first call.

Using this to calculate current Unix time:

> Public Function UnixNow() As Long
>
> ```
>     Dim _TimeSpan As TimeSpan = (DateTime.UtcNow - New DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))
>
>     Return CLng(_TimeSpan.TotalSeconds)
>
> End Function
> ```

Whenever I call UnixTime is giving me the current time, so result is always 0. Any hints?

Comment: I'd suggest using `example.com` for example domain names instead of otherwise registered domains of questionable content.

Comment: You're correct, Joey. I totally forgot about that. I'll use example.com from now on :)

Answer (score 0):

Of course UnixNow will always give you the current time...

Store it and compute the difference

```
Dim unixTimeFirstRequest Long = UnixNow()
Dim post1 String = "http://www.xxx.com/......" & unixTimeFirstRequest & "......"
Dim postReq1 As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(post1), HttpWebRequest)

Dim post2 String = "http://www.xxx.com/......" & UnixNow() - unixTimeFirstRequest & "......"
Dim postReq2 As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(post2), HttpWebRequest)


Dim post3 String = "http://www.xxx.com/......" & UnixNow() - unixTimeFirstRequest & "......"
Dim postReq3 As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(post3), HttpWebRequest)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but didn't work, still gives me 0 as response. It seems so simple, but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Sorry, got the question wrong. 
The UnixNow() code works totally fine on my system.